# if statement evaluate incorrectly when calling contract from another contract on Remix

Tags: transactions, remix

I have a simple piece of code but I can't not get it to work correctly.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Interface {
     function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns(bool);
     function balanceOf(address _owner) public constant returns(uint256); 
}

contract SolidContract is Interface {
    address owner;
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    function SolidContract() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        balances[owner] = 100000;
    }
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns(bool) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value) {
            balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
            balances[_to] += _value;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    function balanceOf(address _owner) public constant returns(uint256) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }
}

contract TestCallingContract {
    Interface c;
    function TestCallingContract(Interface _c) public{
        c = _c;
    }
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns(bool) {
       return c.transfer(_to, _value);
    }
    function balanceOf(address _owner) public constant returns(uint256) {
         return c.balanceOf(_owner);
    }
}
```

When I call `transfer` from `TestCallingContract`, the if statement `if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value)` is always evaluated to false and therefore the transaction cannot go through. If I remove the if statement then everything works. Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: Actually after removing the if statement, even if the transfer returns true, the balance is not altered...

Answer (score 0):

`contract Interface {
     function transfer(address, uint256) public returns(bool) {}
     function balanceOf(address) public constant returns(uint256) {}
}`

It is the syntax problem with the interface...